# What are the differences between MVC controllers (can I inject all controllers in one controller)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, controller, odata

> What are the defferent between   **Controller**(MVC) vs **ApiController** and **BreezeController** and **IHttpController** and **ODataController**?

---

> Why So many controllers in `MVC`? Which one is a main controller? Can i inject the all controllers in  one controller?

Answer (score 2):

- MVC [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is a common controller (the "main" Controller).
- API [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is a MVC controller specific to the [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (the "WebServices") projects.
- The [ODataController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.odatacontroller%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) (this is an ApiController) defines a base class for OData controllers that support writing and reading data using the OData formats.
- [IHttpController](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.ihttpcontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx&ei=JYlCU_OZGrST0QW9sIGQAg&usg=AFQjCNH6XrbXdtLpqxEimA_8hsifvDe4qA&sig2=ExJ7fz7bOu-nUlJqUiIM2A&bvm=bv.64125504,d.d2k) is an interface helping implementing *common* functionality to *custom* HTTP controllers.
- I am not aware about the existence of a "BreezeController" class, but I think [this article](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller) may help.
- There is no need to "inject" one controller into another. Take a look at that [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54576/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Ar), it may help.

Comment: And other controllers means?

Comment: see my edits. And, first of all, what is your programming question/challenge? what are you trying to do? If you try to understand how controllers work, see the last reference in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mvc Controller structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcDemo.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Index()
{return View();}

public ActionResult About()
{return View();}
}
}
```

1.Locating the appropriate action method to call and validating that it can be called.
2.Getting the values to use as the action method's arguments.
3.Handling all errors that might occur during the execution of the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Both MVC controller and API controller are supposed to house nothing but the "EndPoints". The Endpoints in MVC controllers are typically methods of type ActionResult for HTML view, JsonResult to respond to AJAX calls, or simple string for returning a status indicator, whereas the Endpoints in API Controllers can be any custom Class type that are usually represented in JSON Format.

Any http request hits designated endpoint method inside the controller, so you can think of controllers as analogous to "virtual directories" of a website.

All business logic and data processing should be implemented in the Model and Business Logic Layer. The endpoints simply decide which process to direct the request to, and return the result produced by the Model processes.

This article describes a bit more details on the difference between the two:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/webapi-vs-mvc-comparing-apples-oranges-yogi-grantz

Answer (score 0):

MVC Controller is a common controller (the "main" Controller).

API Controller is a MVC controller specific to the WebApi (the "WebServices") projects.

The ODataController (this is an ApiController) defines a base class for OData controllers that support writing and reading data using the OData formats.

IHttpController is an interface helping implementing common functionality to custom HTTP controllers.

I am not aware about the existence of a "BreezeController" class, but I think this article may help.

There is no need to "inject" one controller into another. Take a look at that article, it may help.